# Having trouble positioning a button at the right side of the div in which it resides using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As you can see in the snippet below, I have 1 div which has display property set to flex and then this div has 2 children divs which take flex:1 space ( 50% ). Each of those divs contains 1 button each.

Now the problem is this. I want the first button to be at the start of the first div ( so left side ) and the second button to be at the end of the second div ( so right side ). Currently both buttons are at the left side of their respective divs.

And while we're at it, is using flexbox the best way to create side by side divs like I've done nowadays?

```css
.edit-btn, .submit-btn {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    outline:none;
}
.flex-row {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.flex-column {
    flex: 1;
}
.like, .edit {
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.submit-btn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
.edit-btn {
    background-color: #13aff0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-column">
        <button class="submit-btn like">Like</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
        <a class='edit-btn edit' href="#">Edit</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just setting `flex-direction:row-reverse` for the div of the second column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `.flex-column` wrappers. And use `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
.edit-btn,
.submit-btn {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  outline: none;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.like,
.edit {
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.submit-btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.edit-btn {
  background-color: #13aff0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <button class="submit-btn like">Like</button>
  <a class='edit-btn edit' href="#">Edit</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, good to know that I don't need the .flex-column wrappers since they were a thorn in my eyes anyway.